# Build failed when trying to deploy a MERN stack with tailwind onto Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, mern, tailwind-css

I am trying to deploy a MERN stack application which uses tailwind on the frontend onto Heroku but it returned me 'Build failed'

Here's the build log from Heroku:

```
sh: 1: postcss: not found

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! file sh

npm ERR! errno ENOENT

npm ERR! web_page_react@0.1.0 build:tailwind: `postcss src/tailwind.css -o src/tailwind.generated.css`

npm ERR! spawn ENOENT

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the web_page_react@0.1.0 build:tailwind script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.BI6XT/_logs/2020-07-31T16_43_03_360Z-debug.log

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! web_page_react@0.1.0 prebuild: `npm run build:tailwind`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the web_page_react@0.1.0 prebuild script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.BI6XT/_logs/2020-07-31T16_43_03_389Z-debug.log

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! web-items@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && 

npm run build --prefix client`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the web-items@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.BI6XT/_logs/2020-07-31T16_43_03_414Z-debug.log

-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 
!     Push failed
```

This is the scripts inside my main package.json:

```
{
    "start": "node server",
    "server": "nodemon server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  }
```

This is the script inside my client package.json:

```
{
    "build:tailwind": "postcss src/tailwind.css -o src/tailwind.generated.css",
    "watch:tailwind": "postcss -w src/tailwind.css -o src/tailwind.generated.css",
    "start": "run-p watch:tailwind start:react",
    "start:react": "react-scripts start",
    "prebuild": "npm run build:tailwind",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with what looks like identical project setup. Did you figure the postcss problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it seem not exist `postcss` module in your `package.json` file.

whould u show me your `package.json` file?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with what looks like identical project setup. Do you know if this postcss issue ever got solved?